# Why is Google Recaptcha termed safe

Tags: security, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

How does google differentiates between bot and human using recaptcha, provided the fact that one can trigger click directly using javascript. Am I missing some backend logic here and how does google ensures the validity

I am using ReCaptcha demo as has been available here :- https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo

Comment: ReCaptcha asks visual questions and needs human interaction to solve questions. It detects automatic clicks from real clicks by complex algorithms based on fast click, repetitive clicks in short time and repetitive clicks from same IP and etc... It not always asks questions but when clicks are suspected.

Comment: Yes i read the same but somehow i can trigger click using simple js. It seems i am missing something. I tried it on given link. It didnot suspect it as an automated click.

Comment: It would be helpful to explain what technique you used in JS and how many times you executed it (I would start with at least several hundred clicks, possibly a few thousand). The goal of these systems is not to have zero false-negatives. It is to detect automated *systems*, not single clicks. There is no danger to missing a small number, and it is more important to avoid false positives than to avoid false negatives. "I just drove down a road at higher than the speed limit" does not mean that police do not ticket speeders.